# How to access files created by other apps with mediastore on Android?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am able to read the file i created with mediastore in android 10

But I can't read files created by other apps

'java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000' error occurs when trying to access mediaPlayer from other apps

How can I read files created by other apps?

Below is the code to get the list of files in the MUSIC folder

```
public void getFileListInFolderApiQ(String path) {

    mDataSet.clear();

    Uri externalUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + "tts" + "/"};
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE
    };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(externalUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    Uri testUri = null;

    if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return;
    }

    do {
        String contentUrl = externalUri.toString() + "/" + cursor.getString(0);

        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(externalUri, id);

        String tmpFilename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        testUri = uri;


        mDataSet.add(new CustomTTSListData(tmpFilename, getPathFromUri(testUri), 1, 1, uri));

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Show the code that caused the exception. I dont understand that you tried to start the player with something that you could not get from media store.

Comment: `when trying to access mediaPlayer from other apps` When trying to access a media file from other apps i think.

Comment: Thank you for answer. mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplication(), uri);

java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000 error when calling the code
But the wav file created by my app doesn't throw an error

Comment: You did not even give half an answer. Tell the value of that uri and tell how you obtained it. Show more code. In your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: I added the code to the body

Comment: `java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.:` I see no code with setDataSource. And you did not tell what was listed and what you tried to display. And what the error has to do with your listng.

Comment: `getPathFromUri(testUri)` What is that? What are you doing?

Comment: Save the file path to mDataSet and then
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplication(), mDataSet.get(position).getUri());
I am using it with

Comment: File path? What path? Of which file? A file of your app? Please tell which path exactly. Also tell the value of mDataSet.get(position).getUri().toString(). And i asked what getPathFromUri(testUri) did and you did not answer that question.

Comment: The value of mDataSet.get(position).getUri().toString() is
It has the following format
/storage/emulated/0/Music/tts/20210625_173026_3.wav
getPathFromUri changes the above path to uri format

Comment: I think -well i'm shure-  that getPathFromUri changes an uri to a path. But you should not do such nasty things. Further i still dont know if that uri was of a file of your app or from other app. And you did not tell us that you were going to convert nice uries obtained by querying the media store to file system paths. And i still dont see a setDataSource() call which i asked for two hours ago.